# Resizing colorbox after loading content by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, colorbox

I am opening some HTML content in color-box and data is being populated through Ajax call.For some cases its working fine but for few cases popup is coming as distorted.
I know what is root cause for this but not sure how to fix this issues.Initially I though to add  `$.fn.colorbox.resize();` in my `ajaxComplete` method but this is not working as expected.

After doing some debugging, I found that issues is with using [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) social sharing plugin.
I am also using `AddThis` social sharing plugin and this plugin has some known issues while using with Ajax call.
We need to reinitialize `AddThis` plugin if we loading content through Ajax and loading content using `AddThis`.

So In order AddThis to work, I have to add following code in my `JSP` file which is being used for loading Ajax content.
This JS code is inline and will be triggered when this JSP page content are being loaded using Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config = addthis_config||{};
addthis_config.pubid = '${addThisPubId}';
$.getScript( "https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js?domready=1#pubid=${addThisPubId}");
$(function () {addthis.init();
});
</script>
```

With above code AddThis is working fine.
Since above code is trying to reinitialize its `AddThis` script, so popup content is getting displayed before AddThis finsih loading there content and once AddThis finished its work, its too late to call `$.fn.colorbox.resize()`.

Is there any way I can call `$.fn.colorbox.resize()`, after `AddThis` finished loading its content

Comment: Please post your corresponding code since we can't tell you where tu put your call in the AddThis code

Comment: @user3241019: which code you talking about?

Comment: **Once AddThis finished its work, its too late** then you have to find where to put your line after content loading in the AddThis code, or post it.

Comment: @user3241019: Sorry but still not got what you are looking for..that javascript code which I mentioned in my post is part of HTML being sent from the server and will be executed once data is being loaded on the client side.I have written  `$.fn.colorbox.resize()` in `$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings)`, but by the time `ajaxComplete` is getting executed, AddThis has not finished loading data (Add This load data using a Javascript code I mentioned in my post)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AddThis JavascriptEvents, try [registering an Event Listener](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1365497-addthis-javascript-events#registering-listener) when `addthis` initialization is ready.

```
// Invoked when the AddThis API is ready
function addthisReady(evt) {
    $.fn.colorbox.resize();
}

// Listen for the ready event
addthis.addEventListener('addthis.ready', addthisReady);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I earlier tried this with no sucess, may be I might be doing something wrong.Can you let me know where I need to put `addthis.addEventListener('addthis.ready', addthisReady);` code

Comment: I would put it just before `addthis.init();` as this: 
`$(function () {
addthis.addEventListener('addthis.ready', addthisReady);
addthis.init();
});`